# NullPointerException in conn = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, nullpointerexception

I am using Java 1.4 and tomcat v4.0.

This is the code in my Dao:

```
private DataSource jdbcFactory;
    
    

    public CommonDao() {
            Context c = null;
            if (this.jdbcFactory == null) {
                try {
                    c= new InitialContext();
                    Context envCtx = (Context)c.lookup("java:comp/env");
                    this.jdbcFactory = (DataSource)envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mydb");     
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
        }
    
    public String getParamValue(String param_name) throws SQLException, TestException {
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            String sqlString=null;
            String param_value = null;
            TestException fe = new TestException();
            
            sqlString = "SELECT PARAM_VALUE " +
                        "FROM SAMPLE_TBL " +
                        "WHERE PARAM_NAME = '" + param_name + "' " ;
            
            try {
                conn = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                
                 while (rs.next()) {
                 param_value = rs.getString("PARAM_VALUE");
                }
            } catch(SQLException e){
                fe.setCallingObj("CommonDao.getParamValue");
                fe.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode());
                fe.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage()); 
                fe.setStackTrace(e.getStackTrace());
                throw fe;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                rs.close();
                ps.close();
                conn.close();
            }
    
            return param_value;
            
        }
```

context.xml under META-INF:

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb" global="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@somesitexxx:xxxx:XXXXXX"
    username="someusername" password="somepass" maxActive="1000"
    maxIdle="1000" maxWait="500" />
</Context>
```

web.xml under WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">
<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
        <display-name>LoginController</display-name>
        <description></description>
        <servlet-class>com.Controller.LoginController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LoginController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/rdcdb</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

I am using ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar as well but included or not I am still getting the NPE in conn = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();

this.jdbcFactory -> is also null when debugging.

Can you help me which part I miss?

EDIT: I have now upgraded to java 8 and tomcat 7 and used ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar.
But I am still getting the NPE exception
updated error stacktrace:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.driver.OracleDriver'
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at com.Dao.CommonDao.getParamValue(CommonDao.java:72)
    at com.Dao.CommonDao.checkAvailability(CommonDao.java:411)
    at com.Controller.LoginController.processRequest(LoginController.java:114)
    at com.Controller.LoginController.doGet(LoginController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 27 more
Apr 28, 2022 3:16:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [LoginController] in context with path [/BV_PROBE] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.Dao.CommonDao.getParamValue(CommonDao.java:89)
    at com.Dao.CommonDao.checkAvailability(CommonDao.java:411)
    at com.Controller.LoginController.processRequest(LoginController.java:114)
    at com.Controller.LoginController.doGet(LoginController.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It catches SQLException: Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.driver.OracleDriver'

Comment: Does `Context#lookup` throw an exception?

Comment: @dan1st, no, only on this line conn = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();

Comment: Yes but did an exception occur before that? Was there an exception in `Context#lookup` that you caught?

Comment: It would be easier to increase java version to 8 and increase ojdbc driver version to one that will support java 8 and your database version. Also tomcat version should be upgraded to at least 9

Comment: @dan1st it is not going inside the catch, I also added catch for Exception but it still did not go there. But it did go to the "catch (Exception e) {" when encountered conn = this.jdbcFactory.getConnection();

Comment: Java 1.4 has been out of public support for 14(!) years (and out of extended support for 9), you really should stop using it. You cannot use ojdbc7 with Java 1.4. The **7** in ojdbc7 means it was compiled for Java 7, and Java 1.4 cannot read classes compiled for Java 7.

Comment: In any case, the `NullPointerException` is the wrong thing to focus on. Clearly your JNDI lookup fails (probably due to an UnsupportedClassVersionError because of using ojdbc7). And otherwise, we need to full exception stacktrace of that failure, and also check your logs for other exceptions.

Comment: I have now upgraded to java 8 and tomcat 7 and used ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar.
But I am still getting the NPE. I updated the descript

Comment: Where did you put the ojdbc7 library? The exception indicates it isn't on the classpath of Tomcat.

Comment: Hi, @MarkRotteveel I already resolved the issue thanks to u guys.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that that is the only constructor ...

If `jdbcFactory` is `null`, that means that in the following code:

```
try {
    c = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) c.lookup("java:comp/env");
    this.jdbcFactory = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mydb");     
} catch (NamingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

either the second `lookup` call returned `null` or you threw and caught a `NamingException`.  According to the `Context` javadocs, a `lookup` call may return `null`, it your application bound `null` to the name.

---

However ... on rereading your question, I noticed this:

> I am using Java 1.4 and Tomcat v4.0.

These are truly ancient versions.  Both are end-of-life.  Tomcat 4 was end-of-life prior to 2012<sup>1</sup>, and Java 1.4.2 in 2013.   You are missing nearly 10 years worth of security patches.

And this:

> I am using ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar

That is a driver for Java 7.  I doubt that it will work with Java 1.4.

According to what I have read, you should be using an ojdbc.14 driver with Java 1.4.  It is highly unlikely that you can find one that is compatible with a recent Oracle database.

---

<sup>1 - 2012 is when Tomcat 5 was officially end-of-life.  The end-of-life for earlier versions was not formally announced.  But the last patch release of Tomcat 4 was in 2009.</sup>

Comment: Hi, yes because I am tasked to fix the old project to life. I have used ojdbc 14 and put it in build path and web-inf/lib as well but error still persists.

Comment: Probably because ojdbc14 is too old for your database.

Comment: The way to get your project working will be to **first** upgrade to a recent Java and Tomcat.  You need a Java version that is supported for your Oracle database.   So ... work backwards from the database version.

Comment: The app is still running in production though. But i am tasked to access repo. Is that still the case?

Comment: Is what still the case?  If you are changing your app to talk to Oracle ... where it didn't before ... you need to be using a version of Java that is supported by your **current** Oracle database.

Comment: I am having a hardtime on this because it is a really old app. Thanks btw.! It is talking to oracle before and is using ojdbc14. but will try to change the version of java

Comment: *"It is talking to Oracle before"*.  Which version of Oracle?  And what you mean by "before"?  Before you started changing things?  Before they upgraded your Oracle DB?  Something else?

Comment: Hmm, because the app is running in prod and using the ojdbc 14. And they are able to use that webapp until now. In my case I need to access the its repository but the repository is not working fine. I need to access this because IE is not going to have support anymore, and I need to tweak some codes, but after accessing it, the db access is the blocker. Which is weird because the webapp in production is connecting to the oracle but the repo is not

Comment: Well perhaps the versions are not the problem then.  Perhaps the problem is your `<Resource ...>` element or firewalls or something.  You need to start doing some proper diagnostic investigation for yourself.  Or get a more experienced colleague to help you.

Comment: Yeap, maybe it is. Will do some research on this one...